# PHP - Cookie isn't working?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Why can't I delete this Cookie?

When a user logs in authenticate_user() is run. When the user logs out logout() is run. When the class is run status is generated via update_status().

How do I kill the status cookie? No matter what I try it exists and the user cannot log out.

[CODE REMOVED]

Solved it.

When deleting a cookie you must specify what directories the cookie can access.

```
Not Deleted
setcookie("status", "", (time()+3600), '/');
setcookie("status", "", (time()-3600));

Deleted
setcookie("status", "", (time()+3600), '/');
setcookie("status", "", (time()-3600), '/');
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, so I'm not putting it as an answer, but why are you making your life difficult by using the cookie *as well*, rather than just doing it all in the session?  The way you're doing things looks more complex and I can't really see the point.  If you leave it all in the session, then you can just `session_destroy` and they're done.

Comment: I seem to have answered at the same time you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Is status a session cookie? If it is then `$_COOKIE['status']` won't exist.

Use `session_destroy()` to remove it, make sure you have `session_start()` at the top of the page first though (this is probably why your having problems with sessions not working).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
setcookie("status", "", time()-3600, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a grey area.

First thing of note is that you are trying to delete the cvookie by setting its expiry to an hour ago - but what time zone is your script running in? And what time zone is the client in?

Also, I've seen behaviour which seems to be explained by browsers hanging on to cookies when the expiry time is subsequently set to a date in the past (**long** in the past - not a timezone thing).

The mere presence of a cookie should NEVER be treated as evidence of authentication - this should be a handle to data stored serverside. So the solution is to overwrite the VALUE of the cookie to a nonsense value - not change its expiry time.